# atos returning the same address for arm64

Tags: ios, appcelerator, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash, crittercism

Below is a portion of the crash log for my application which occurred in iPhone 6 Plus (arm64):

```
    0     libobjc.A.dylib                       0x35b4ef66 objc_msgSend + 6
    1     UIKit                                 0x2a905dd1 -[UIScrollView setContentOffset:] + 626
    2     UIKit                                 0x2aa871b9 -[UIAnimator(Static) _advanceAnimationsOfType:withTimestamp:] + 270
    3     UIKit                                 0x2aa870a5 -[UIAnimator(Static) _LCDHeartbeatCallback:] + 50
    4     QuartzCore                            0x2a34cb67 _ZN2CA7Display15DisplayLinkItem8dispatchEv + 96
    5     QuartzCore                            0x2a34c9cf _ZN2CA7Display11DisplayLink14dispatch_itemsEyyy + 364
    6     IOMobileFramebuffer                   0x2f0f9c03 IOMobileFramebufferVsyncNotifyFunc + 88
    7     IOKit                                 0x28204d0d IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage + 254
    8     CoreFoundation                        0x27240555 __CFMachPortPerform + 130
    9     CoreFoundation                        0x27250a4b __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 32
    10   CoreFoundation                         0x272509e7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 344
    11   CoreFoundation                         0x2724f009 __CFRunLoopRun + 1606
    12   CoreFoundation                         0x2719a9a1 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 474
    13   CoreFoundation                         0x2719a7b3 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104
    14   GraphicsServices                       0x2eb421a9 GSEventRunModal + 134
    15   UIKit                                  0x2a94b635 UIApplicationMain + 1438
    16   MyOwnApp                               0x00039c67 main (main.m:37)
    17   libdyld.dylib                          0x36110aaf start + 0
```

I have verified the UUID of the .app file and the .dsym file using the dwarfdump and verified that they both have the same UUID. The UUID mention in the crash report is mentioned for arm64.

Now when I execute the command:

```
    atos -arch arm64 MyOwnApp.app/MyOwnApp 0x00039c67
```

The output of the command is the same hex address 0x00039c67. But when I change the arch from arm64 to armv7, then it specifies a method name.

Also if I see main.m, line 37 in the build output (I am coding in Appcelerator), then it just calls UIApplication function, which I think might be the entry point of the application. I am not into iOS native development.

Can someone please help me in this regard.

Comment: Has anyone faced this type of an issue?

Answer (score 0):

It's **stack** trace, so most recent calls are on top.
Please provide error message.

Comment: The name and reason reported SIGSEGV and SEGV_ACCERR. Is this information you were looking for or is there anything specific. I checked the other information, but I would not find one.

Comment: Any idea on what could be the issue that atos is giving the same address as the output for arm64 architecture.